# Can't find custom package

Tags: go

I'm tryng to create a custom package in go: i created folder project:

```
my_project
|_database
  |_database.go
main.go
```

but when i try to import it gaves me this error: "could not import database (no package for import database)"

i try to run "go init" as written in some tutorial and created a "go.mod" file, then i run "go install" and works fine, but in the main.go it still not working.
The project structure is now this:

```
my_project
|_database
  |_database.go
  |_go.mod
  |_go.sum
main.go
```

I work on windows with visual studio code

Here is how i import the package:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    ...
    "database"
)

function main() {
```

Comment: How are you importing your custom `database` package in `main.go`? Please add that in your question.

Comment: @Azeem ok, I edit the question

Comment: Try: `"./database"` instead of `"database"`.

Comment: Question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a few things.

Make sure your database.go is the following way:

> it should contain a package name this case is database, comment the
>   function/s that need to be used outside this package, use func instead
>   of function. and comment code and capitalize function name so it can
>   be exported.

```
package database

import "fmt"

// Connect function to connect to my database
func Connect(){
   fmt.Print("connected...")
}
```

your main.go should be the following.

> use func instead of function, import database based on folder position
>   this case is ./ use the package name database. because this function
>   does not belong from current package main.

```
package main

import "./database"

func main() {
   database.Connect()
}
```

This should be your folder structure.

```
my_project
|_database
  |_database.go
main.go
go.mod 
go.sum
```